# How does the Ihttphandler interface expose the httpcontext object

Tags: httpcontext, ihttphandler

Hello I see on msnd that anything that inherits from the Ihttphandler interface has access to a httpcontext object (under the remarks section of the page in below link)

[msdn HTTPContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx)

My question is how does the interface expose this object...I don't see any property of type httpcontext in the interface. I do see the "ProcessRequest" method that is taking in an httpcontext object. But i'm not seeing how that is resulting in the httpcontext object being exsposed directly from the interface as the msnd page says.

Forgive me if i'm missing a key concept here, fairly new to this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is passed into the ProcessContext method only. The handler then interacts with that HttpContext instance as it's the context for the request. You can pass around the context instance to various other methods and such as much as you would like.

Why it is done this way becomes more clear if you look at the documentation about the IsReusable property. When that property is `true`, multiple requests can be served by the same handler instance, and thus they must be supplied a separate HttpContext to work.

Now, if you specify IsReusable as `false`, you can then store the HttpContext instance from ProcessRequest in a property on the instance. Not sharing the handler can cause performance issues under some scenarios, but you likely won't need to worry about that.

Comment: oh so its the specific handler itself that is exsposing the httpcontext object to say a class that is just using system.web?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure what you are saying specifically there. Basically what you are saying is this. I have a class SomeHandler which implements IHttpHandler, and asp.net knows about IHttpHandler. When a request comes in, asp.net goes and looks who should be handling it, finds your handler, and calls your ProcessRequest method and gives YOU the HttpContext. That's why it's not needed to be exposed anywhere. You don't need to let other people know about the context, all that needs to happen is for asp.net to let you know about the context.

Comment: Are you asking where you can find the HttpContext instance from someplace other than IHttpHandler?

Comment: I was really looking for what is creating the original httpcontext object. Msdn makes it sound as if it coming from the interface somehow. Just wondering how a simple business class can see the httpcontext object, and where exactly it is coming from. From what I understand you are saying is that ASP.net is somehow providing it

Comment: yea I'm wondering where its being instantiated, and how its being passed down, I guess that concerns that are just the ASP back end I don't need to worry about them.

Comment: yeah, the asp.net runtime creates it and passes it to your handler. if you need to access the context from other classes either pass the context you got from in IHttpHandler or you can use the HttpContext.Current property.